# Trying to remember a sci fi book title I read in the 80s

Tags: story-identification, novel

Female protagonist. Story starts out with her discovering that she has amnesia from a crash landing on a strange backwards world. She has a green triangle that glows in her forehead and special powers. She wanders around lost, trying to figure out who she is. Many of the people she meets on the strange world think she is either a goddess or a freak and is to be feared or worshipped. She does meet an old healer woman, I think blind, who befriends and helps her.

By the end of the story she figures out who she is and is subsequently found by her male partner or crew. I can't remember the title of this book, the author, or the main character's name!

It's not part of a series or trilogy. I'm pretty sure it was written in the 80s, but maybe late 70s? Also, I was a teenager when I read it so it might have been a young adult sci fi book.

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but you might enjoy [this](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/207774.Rebel_Ice). It has a very similar plot

Comment: Some of the stuff at the end of _Rebel Ice_ won't make much sense since it is book 6 (out of 10).  I enjoyed the series, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds a bit like Birthgrave by Tanith Lee. [Wikipedia has a summary of the book here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Birthgrave).

The protagonist, Karrakaz, wakes alone and with amnesia:

> To wake, and not to know where, or who you are, not even to know what you are—whether a thing with legs and arms, or a beast, or a brain in the hull of a great fish—that is a strange awakening. But after a while, uncurling in the darkness, I began to discover myself, and I was a woman.

The blind woman would be Kotta:

> "Ettook must have the mask,” Kotta said. “It is his right. Later he will have a right to your body, when you are delivered of the child.”
>   “I must not show my face,” I whispered.
>   She gave a fox’s bark of laughter.
>   “Oh, so you learn the tribal ways so soon. That is good. Well, no fear that Kotta will see your face. Kotta is blind.”

Karrakaz has a glowing, green triangle made from jade in her forehead.